# C++ STL Vector: Push_back taking reference

Tags: c++, stl

From the cpp documentation for `std::vector`, I see this:

```
void push_back ( const T& x );
```

I understand that `push_back` makes a copy of the object that I pass. But, why is the signature `const T& ?` By looking at this, I initially thought it takes a `const` reference of whatever object that I push to the `vector`.

Comment: I will do that. I realized it only yesterday and I am doing it from then on. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other option would be

```
void push_back(T x);
```

that is, taking `x` by value.  However, this would (in C++03) result in creating an extra copy of `x` (the copy in the arguments to `push_back`).  Taking `x` by const reference avoids this.

Let's look at the stack for a call `v.push_back(T())` taken by value:

```
v.push_back(T());                      // instance of T
void std::vector<T>::push_back(T x)    // copy of T
new (data_[size_ - 1]) T(x)            // copy of copy of T
```

Taking by const reference we get:

```
v.push_back(T());                             // instance of T
void std::vector<T>::push_back(const T &x)    // const reference to T
new (data_[size_ - 1]) T(x)                   // copy of T
```

In C++11 it would be possible (though unnecessary) to take `x` by value and use `std::move` to move it onto the vector:

```
v.push_back(T());                             // instance of T
void std::vector<T>::push_back(T x)           // copy of T
new (data_[size_ - 1]) T(std::move(x))        // move the copy of T
```

Comment: It's still preferable to have it take `T const&` in C++11 (alongside a `T&&` overload), as not all objects can be efficiently moved.

Answer (score 9):

The `object` you push is passed by reference to avoid `extra copy`. Than a copy is placed in the `vector`.

Answer (score 9):

Just to clarify the "extra copy" @ecatmur describes, if `push_back` received its argument by value, what would happen would be that you'd start with your object. A copy of that would be passed to `push_back` as its parameter. Then `push_back` would create a copy of *that* to put into the vector itself.

Since the real implementation of `push_back` receives its argument by reference, it (`push_back`) creates the new object in the vector directly as a copy of your original object.

As already mentioned, yes, with C++11 using move semantics, it would be possible (though probably not particularly advantageous) to pass the argument by value, and then move the value from that argument into the new object in the vector. If what you were putting in the vector was, say, a string that mostly just contains a pointer and a couple of "book keeping" fields (amount of memory allocated, amount of memory currently in use), that would be *almost* as efficient as passing a reference, because a move can just do a shallow copy -- copy the pointer and book keeping values themselves, instead of all the data it points at. If, however, the object in question held all its data directly (i.e., not a pointer), then a move would be just as slow as a copy.

Passing by reference, avoids *all* that copying, so even for something like a string, it's generally faster still (for a case like this that the original object can't be invalidated). It also has the minor advantage of working with C++98/03, not just C++11.